# How to layout three buttons evenly located under LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three buttons need to be located in one line at the bottom of the screen. Below is the code in activity xml. In order to make the three button takes even space, I wrap each of them inside a LinearLayout and set the layout `android:layout_weight` to 1 and `android:layout_gravity` to center.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90px"
        android:background="#88104502"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/goBack"
                android:layout_width="70px"
                android:layout_height="80px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:onClick="toHomePage" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/findPlant"
                android:layout_width="70px"
                android:layout_height="80px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/flowr"
                android:onClick="toImagePage" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/plantList"
                android:layout_width="70px"
                android:layout_height="80px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/list" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

But it the button is not located in the center of the LinearLayout. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

You can see that each button is located on the left of the LinearLayout. How to make them center located?

Comment: why are you use three different Linear Layout? It's also done using one main LinearLayout and give equal weight to 3 button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this. I use your code only give gravity to linear layout.If you do not want to use this much of LinearLayout use only one main LinearLayout and give equal weight to 3 buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90px"
    android:background="#88104502"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goBack"
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:onClick="toHomePage" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findPlant"
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:onClick="toImagePage" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plantList"
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a button with an image you can use ImageButton instead of Button, and you can try like this, and instead using nested layout you can give directly weight to ImageButton.

If you want to style a button you can use `AppCompatImageButton` in that you can use `app:backgroundTint` to change the background.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90px"
    android:background="#88104502"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/goBack"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="toHomePage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/findPlant"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="toImagePage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/plantList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="toImagePage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is the **cleanest** (and also the **fastest**) layout among all the answers. Keep it **simple: performances** are relevant. +1

Answer (score 0):

you can create an empty view as the padding.  this way the spacing will always be the same even if the icon widths are different.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90px"
    android:background="#88104502"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View 
           android:layout_weight="1"                       
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="0dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:layout_height="80px" 
            android:background="@drawable/list" />
        <View 
           android:layout_weight="1"                       
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="0dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:layout_height="80px" 
            android:background="@drawable/list" />
        <View 
           android:layout_weight="1"                       
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="0dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:layout_height="80px" 
            android:background="@drawable/list" />
      <View 
           android:layout_weight="1"                       
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gravity instead of layout_gravity.